# same query in procedure take different time

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, procedure, execution-time

i have a same code in procedure with only 1 different (date variable).
in my code i have 27 p_dt variable. Code below is not full.
when i run procedure with p_dt it cost more than 10hours but when i write to_date('01.01.2020','dd.mm.yyyy') instead p_dt it cost 300 sec

```
create or replace ru.t_maha(p_dt in date default trunc(sysdate) -1) as
begin

delete from t_maha_1 
where dt = to_date(add_months(trunc(p_dt,'MONTH'),-1),'dd.mm.yyyy');
commit;

insert into t_maha_1
with scheta_Snt as (
select 
inn,
add_months(trunc(p_dt,'MONTH'),-1) || last_Day(add_months(trunc(p_dt,'MONTH'),-1)) interval,
sum(case when t.dt_open between add_months(trunc(p_dt,'MONTH'),-1) and last_Day(add_months(trunc(p_dt,'MONTH'),-1)) then value_nat end ) scheta_snt
from fct_Carry t 
)
select * from scheta_snt
join scheta_pop (same subquery but for another calculate)
join dep_snt (same subquery but for another calculate)
join dep_pop (same subquery but for another calculate)
```

Comment: please run an explain plan and post the results and post table and index DDL. nobody here can just read a query and determine what is slow about it.

Comment: for explain plan query , i can write only date ('dd.mm.yyyy') instead of variable p_dt
and execution plan normal but idk how to take explain plan for query with variable 
or if i show explain plan with date is enough ?